# CD in to a directory path with illegal chars that is stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have situation. It is about applying a cd command to a path of a directory that I will receive as an argument from a command line and pass it in to variable inside a script. I will however explain the gist of my problem below in a few steps. This is really silly as there is something here that I am not seeing even though my eyes are wide open.

```
~> cd /home/av/Exercise_Files/FOO\ -\ 2005\ _\ CONT\ _\ BAR\ _\ 20190527\;\ This\ -\ is\ -\ crap/
```

Result:

```
~/Exercise_Files/FOO - 2005 _ CONT _ BAR _ 20190527; This - is - crap>
```

The previous execution works with that directory name that has all sorts of stuff to mess up the shell while it expands the directory name in to all sorts of god awful interpretations.

The problem is explained below:

when I do:

```
~> c="/home/av/Exercise_Files/FOO\ -\ 2005\ _\ CONT\ _\ BAR\ _\ 20190527\;\ This\ -\ is\ -\ crap/"
```

and I do an echo:

```
~> echo $c
/home/av/Exercise_Files/FOO\ -\ 2005\ _\ CONT\ _\ BAR\ _\ 20190527\;\ This\ -\ is\ -\ crap/
```

I get everything as it should with the illegal chars properly escaped and stored in to the variable c;

but then if I do this:

```
~> cd "$c"
-bash: cd: /home/av/Exercise_Files/FOO\ -\ 2005\ _\ CONT\ _\ BAR\ _\ 20190527\;\ This\ -\ is\ -\ crap/: No such file or directory
```

I get an error.

Can anyone please shed some light in to what I can do to resolve this problem? In fact I also have to use this procedure inside an rsync too. When i use this variable passing method in there, rsync also throws an error when it tries to change the directory for the purpose of syncing files but the problem that I explained above is the core one that is messing up my script.

Comment: Don't ever trust `echo`. It's doesn't provide a useful representation of what your contents are. Use `printf '%q\n' "$c"`

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is rather closely related as well.

Comment: I never tried experimenting with `printf` although I have heard good things about this command when it comes to printing outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're essentially double-escaping. If you need to `cd` to a folder called `foo bar`, then either `cd foo\ bar` or `cd "foo bar"` will work, but `cd "foo\ bar"` (the equivalent of what you're doing) will not, as it's actually looking for a folder called `foo\ bar`.

Comment: This is true, certainly, but without explaining the difference between syntactic and literal quotes/escapes/etc and which parsing steps do and don't take place after parameter expansion, it's not necessarily clear to the OP *why* their original attempt was wrong. (OTOH, I'm 100% certain we have duplicates that cover that ground).

Comment: This is what I did after I read the comment from Joseph
`~> c="/home/ayyappaas/Exercise_Files/FOO - 2005 _ CONT _ BAR _ 20190527; This - is - crap"`

`~> cd "$c" `                                                                                                         `~/Exercise_Files/FOO - 2005 _ CONT _ BAR _ 20190527; This - is - crap> `

It worked.

Really appreciate both of your comments on this:) Awesome community!